# PHP Array Multiple fields looping Array from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops, pivot

I want to add more columns to my output in the following code. I have been trying more than 7 hours and still could not figure out how.

```
$sub=array();
$query=mysql_query("SELECT regd, name, roll, Subject, 
  SUM( Mark_score ) / SUM( Full_Mark ) *100 AS hl, 
  SUM( Full_Mark ) AS hm
  FROM entry
  WHERE Year = '2013'
  AND Section = 'A'
  AND Name_of_exam = 'First Term Exam'
  GROUP BY regd, Subject");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){ 
  $sub[$row['regd']][$row['Subject']] = $row['hl']; 
}
$subkey=key($sub); //get the 1st regd key, to be used to get the Subject keys

echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>regd</td>';
echo '<td>name</td>';
foreach($sub[$subkey] as $keys=>$vals){
  echo "<td>".$keys."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
foreach($sub as $key=>$val){ //loop through each regd value, creating a row
  echo "<tr>";
  echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$name.'</td>';//How do I put name array here?
  foreach($val as $v){ //loop through each Subjects for each regd
    echo '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

I want to add `name` field and `roll` field to the output. Thanks for your input.

Updated with table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entry` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `regd` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `rollno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `section` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `univ_roll` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `year` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Name_of_exam` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `Mark_score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Full_Mark` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `regd` (`regd`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: thanks for your input. will surely check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an addon to existing code so the following should work without breaking it

```
$sub = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT regd, name, rollno as roll, Subject,
SUM( Mark_score ) / SUM( Full_Mark ) *100 AS hl,
SUM( Full_Mark ) AS hm
FROM entry
WHERE Year = '2013'
AND Section = 'A'
AND Name_of_exam = 'First Term Exam'
GROUP BY regd, Subject");
$array = array(); //create new array
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $sub[$row['regd']][$row['Subject']] = $row['hl'];

//by doing this, you preserve existing code
    $array[$row['regd']]['roll'] = $row['roll'];
    $array[$row['regd']]['name'] = $row['name'];
}
$subkey = key($sub); //get the 1st regd key, to be used to get the Subject keys

echo "<table border=1>";
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>regd</td>';
echo '<td>name</td>';
echo '<td>roll</td>';
foreach ($sub[$subkey] as $keys => $vals) {
    echo "<td>".$keys."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
foreach ($sub as $key => $val) { //loop through each regd value, creating a row
    echo "<tr>";
    echo '<td>'.$key.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$array[$key]['name'].'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$array[$key]['roll'].'</td>';
    foreach ($val as $v) { //loop through each Subjects for each regd
        echo '<td>'.$v.'</td>';
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: it does output anything. I don't change anything.

Comment: Well if there are no results, then the problem is in your mysql query, this will at the very least add a column...

Comment: Thanks for your input, only name and roll field go blank. I will recheck my code. Anyway is there anything wrong with this sql query?

Comment: If there is no error message it could be that no rows match the conditions in the WHERE clause. After $subkey = key($sub), do var_dump($sub) and it will give you an array if there are results. If the array is empty, then you have no results. Then remove conditions 1 by 1 (starting with the group by) until you have results. That way you will know where it breaks.

Comment: The var_dump(); output everythings. but in the table, name and roll go blank.

Comment: I see, I updated query, does this output anything? If not, show your database.

Comment: This function echo "<pre>";
print_r($sub);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<br />";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "</pre>"; outputs things correctly, but I don't understand why name and roll go blank. Please can you suggest an alternative.

Comment: So there is something in the $array or they are empty? Also, did you try with the SQL query I updated a few minutes ago? Also, can you show your database?

Comment: I will update my question with database. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Ah you see, in your database, the roll column is named rollno (or maybe univ_roll?), you should have had errors with your query. Updated the answer, hoping this time it works

Comment: The result of print_r($array) is Array
(
    [14] => Array
        (
            [Roluaha] => Roluaha
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [Nundika] => Nundika
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [Ruatdika] => Ruatdika
        )
) so name exist in the array. So I change roll to rollno in my table. it is still the same.

Comment: Ahh you have to take whole code again, I noticed it would do that and fixed it already. It should say [14] => Array ([name] => Roluaha)

Comment: It produces more errors. Foreach error and mysql_fetch_assoc error.

Comment: Also updated answer, it might eliminate errors you are getting.

Comment: I create more array like this $name = array();
$roll=array(); and it is almost working, rollno is display now. but only first letter of name is displayed. What could be going wrong...

Comment: After trial and error, I solved the problem with the help of your code..here is how I echo echo '<td>'.$hming[$key].'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$roll[$key]['rollno'].'</td>'; please check whether it is normal or not. Thanks.

Comment: Well it should work with a single array, what is hming^

Comment: $hming an array name for name column.